# Is there a good way to convert a speed number on an eliptical to mph?

Tags: speed, elliptical

What is the meaning of the speed indication on an elliptical?  It ranges up to about 
9 or 10 at what is a high speed run for me.  Is there an approximate conversion to mph?

Comment: Please specify which model you are using, I am pretty sure there is no standard between manufacturers.

Answer (score 3):

It would likely be dependent upon your machine but I did find this.

> Elliptical machines calculate average speed based on thousands of
>   readings taken throughout your workout. Most machines measure your
>   speed every few seconds and record the information in the elliptical's
>   computer. Average speed is typically available in real time and as a
>   final summary of your elliptical training session. Speed is normally
>   denoted in miles per hour and is carried to one decimal place -- for
>   example, an average speed of 5.2 mph.

Read more: http://www.livestrong.com/article/396841-the-average-speed-on-an-elliptical/#ixzz2OB9id5Is